# string patterns in findInLine method in Java

Tags: java, string, methods

What are the string patterns that we can use with findInLine() method.  For example if input is an email address e.g vinny.kinny@gmail.com, how do i find only "vinny.kinny" from the input using the findInLine() method in java.

Answer (score 1):

look at regular expression in java:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/

Answer (score 1):

When you write about a method, it is better to specify in which class (of which package/library, etc.) it can be found.
I don't know the whole Java API, far from it, but I never heard of a findInLine() method.
Unless you meant to write this method yourself, this isn't very clear...

If you plan to write this method, you can use any method in [String](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class. For example, indexOf() can allow you to find the index of "@" and you can then use the substring() method to extract the part before it.
Or you can use regular expressions if you need lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

No a direct ansewr to your question but I'll use a StringTokenizer for that:

```
new StringTokenizer(emailString, "@");
```

Comment: Quote, javadoc: *"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code."* - `String.split()` is the recommended way to split Strings

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I was not aware about that. I should read more carefully the Javadoc of all the classes I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about the `findInLine()` method of the `Scanner` class,
those are regex patterns as described in the Javadoc for  [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

[`Sanner#findInLine(String regExp)`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.lang.String%29) takes the same pattern like [`String#split(String regExp)`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). It is a regular expression (Java style) and a good documentation can be found in the javaDoc of the [`Pattern`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetUserName {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userName;  
  System.out.println("Enter your email address: ");
  userName = scn.findInLine(Pattern.compile("[a-z]+"));

  System.out.println(userName);
 }

}
```

The output from the console window:

```
Enter your email address:
thyaga@gmail.com
thyaga
```

--------------------->

This is what i learnt: the Pattern class, FindInLine method and how to use the pattern parameter, regex constructs.

Thank you all, thanks again for the help you provided !

PS: the regex for the email is not complete and has to be refined.